# Sugar cube is filled with liquid (coffee), only if corner is sinked for few millimeters

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Sorry for quite stupid question, but I could not find answer for it (perhaps my question is wrong).

I noticed one thing about sugar cubes. When I sink one corner of cube in coffee, just for few millimeters, after a few seconds it's already turning brown (filled with coffee, so to say). Another thing, if I sink it for a short period of time and take it out, coffee liquid stops spreading, if I sink it again it continues.

Why this is happening?

Comment: This is simply [capillary action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_action); it has to do with physics rather than chemistry.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the liquid stops spreading'?

Comment: @Joel , well coffee is filling cube (sugar cube is becoming brown), when I take it away from coffee it stops filling

Comment: Oh right! Look into @Ivan Neretin comment.